# drag-sort-listview Drag is not working Android

Tags: java, android, sorting, listview, drag-and-drop

I'm using [drag-sort-listview](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) to sort rows of my `ListView`, and I have created a demo using this library, but it is not working. When I try to drag rows it is not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
            "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };

    public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
            "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
            "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
            "Mixed Fruits" };

    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.drag,
            R.drawable.drag, R.drawable.drag, R.drawable.drag };

    //ListView listView;
    DragSortListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }
        listView = (DragSortListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        final CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listView.setDropListener(new DropListener() {

             @Override
                public void drop(int from, int to) {
                    if (from != to) {
                        //DragSortListView list = getListView();
                        RowItem item = adapter.getItem(from);
                        adapter.remove(item);
                        adapter.insert(item, to);
                        listView.moveCheckState(from, to);

                        //Log.d("DSLV", "Selected item is " + listView.getCheckedItemPosition());
                    }
                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item "
                + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.testingui"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
        dslv:drag_enabled="true"
        dslv:drag_handle_id="@drawable/drag"
        dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
        dslv:drag_start_mode="onMove"
        dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
        dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
        dslv:remove_enabled="true"
        dslv:remove_mode="flingRemove"
        dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
        dslv:sort_enabled="true"
        dslv:track_drag_sort="true"
        dslv:use_default_controller="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### CustomListViewAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDesc;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descs);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titles);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icons);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

#### list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icons"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icons"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icons"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### RowItem.java

```
public class RowItem {
    private int imageId;
    private String title;
    private String desc;

    public RowItem(int imageId, String title, String desc) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + "\n" + desc;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Drag handle Id in DragSortListView tag in Xml

```
         dslv:drag_handle_id="@id/drag_handle"
```

Make an id.xml file and put drag handle id as above to make it common and use the same id on dragable handle image view in your row item.

Hope it helps.